# Atom with typescript - see argument list

Tags: typescript, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I've started to use Atom now, and I've installed `nuclide` package and `atom-typescript`.

When I try to type for example `fs.readFile` it gives me nice autocomplete, but it cuts the arguments, so I cannot see all of them:

[image]

Is there some kind of shortcut/ setting so I can see the list of arguments?

Comment: When using Typescript, my go-to IDE is VsCode for the best development environment.

Comment: @GieSpaepen With all respect to your personal preferences, I think it's a bad habit to recommend software B when the question is explicitly about software A. Answers should stay on-topic rather than recommending opinion-based alternatives.

Comment: Have you installed `atom-ide-ui`, as suggested in the `atom-typescript` [README](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#readme)?